# Filtering null values when casting - using CASE statements

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I've been trying to query rows with a date field up to a threshold. For reasons beyond my control, all fields are varchar. I'm trying to filter out null values which case an error when cast. My latest attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM a_table AS t
WHERE (
    CASE
        when t.dateField is not null then cast(t.datefield as date)
        else cast('2000-01-01' as date)
    END
) <= cast('2017-08-19' as date) ;
```

The above code still hits an error trying to cast "" to a date.

I thought this would be a common problem but I can't seem to find an idiom to achieve this, which makes me think I'm barking up the wrong tree. Can anyone point me to the correct one?

EDIT: Where entries are not null, they have been entered as DD/MM/YYYY.

Comment: What is the data type of `dateField`?  Based on the name a very reasonable assumption is that the type is a `date`.  However, your code is casting it to a date -- and then you are getting an error.  Something is amiss.

Comment: As stated, it is varchar.

Comment: As a side note: that's a CASE _expression_, not a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM a_table AS t
WHERE coalesce(t.dateField, '2000-01-01') <= '2017-08-19'::date;
```

I'm not sure why you would want to coalesce a "dateField" column to a date.  Seems like it already should be a date.

You can also express this as:

```
WHERE t.dateField <= '2017-09-19' OR t.dateField IS NULL
```

If you want to convert a column in the format DD/MM/YYYY to a date, then use `to_date()`:

```
WHERE to_date(t.dateField, 'DD/MM/YYYY') <= '2017-09-19' OR t.dateField IS NULL
```

Comment: As I said, it's a varchar field. Dates have been manually entered in format DD/MM/YYYY. I will add this detail to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

As proposed by [GordonLinoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68850837/5882823) you can skip not valid values from casting

```
SELECT *
FROM a_table AS t
WHERE t.dateField IS NULL 
  OR dateField = '' 
  OR cast(t.datefield as date) < cast('19/08/2017' as date)
```